# Unable to get the declared variable value in javascript

Tags: javascript

Unable to get the class value out side the getJSON scope. Alert declared inside displays value but outside doesn't.

```
// Getting classes based on classID
                        var ClassID = {"ClassID": item.ClassId};
                        var Class="";
                        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetClassesByID","Catalogue")', ClassID, function (Val) {
                            Class=Val;
                           alert("Inside Value " +Class);
                        });

html= html+'<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7 dvpadding isbnnum"><p><b>CLASS - ('+Class+')</b></p></div>';
```

I just want to update the Class mentioned in above html from the value got from ajax call

Comment: `Class=Val;` is executed after `alert("Outside Value " +Class);` , in other words `getJSON` is asynchronous. The scope is correct, but the execution order is not as you expect here.

Answer (score 3):

.getJSON is asynchronous. You're calling alert outside of it which is synchronous. You need to call a function once .getJson is successful like:

```
// Getting classes based on classID
var ClassID = {
  "ClassID": item.ClassId
};
var Class = "";
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetClassesByID","Catalogue")', ClassID, logData(val));

function logData(val) {
  Class = Val;
  alert("Outside Value " + Class);
}
```

Comment: I have declared it globally.

Comment: Yes it's declared globally, but that .getJSON function returns data whenever it wants to because it is an ajax call. It is async, meaning it will return after the alert will, thus you need a callback function

Comment: If this helped you, please checkmark to the left of the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an empty string is because of the way javascript and callbacks work.

This is what you are expecting to happen:

1. class = ""
2. $getJSON
3. Class = val
4. alert(Class)

This is what is happening though:

1. class = ""
2. $getJSON
3. alert(Class)
4. Class = val

The reason beeing that 'Class = val" is inside a `callback` which is basicly just an action that is supposed to happen once $getJSON is done.

However since $getJSON could take a few seconds, whatever is below $getJSON will be run first.

You can think of $getJSON as an assignment that happens. That line of code will execute VERY fast, just as fast as any other line of code. But because you provided a callback, the callback part of the line will only be executed once the JSON was actually fetched which could be at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread the scope completely. Sorry.

Comment: Its in the right scope but the expected value is set asynchronously